# Send tidings to the disbelievers?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, non-muslim, jahannam

It is narrated in: http://sunnah.com/urn/1316410/

> It was narrated from Salim that his father said:
> “A Bedouin came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, my father used to uphold the ties of kinship, and so and so forth, where is he?’ He said: ‘In the Fire.’ It was as if he found that difficult to bear. Then he said: ‘O Messenger of Allah. Where is your father?’ The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: ‘Whenever you pass by the grave of an idolater, give him the tidings of Hell-fire.’ The Bedouin later became Muslim, and he said: ‘The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) gave me a difficult task. I never passed the grave of an idolater but I gave him the tidings of Hell-fire.’”

This same narration is found in books like Al-Mo'jam Al-Kabeer by Al-Tabaran and there seems to be some scholarly dispute over the grading of it. The classical opinion is that it is weak, whilst contemporary scholars like Al-Albani graded it sahih. Regardless of the grading of the narration, what should be made from it? Anytime we pass a grave of a disbeliever, should we laugh and mockingly give them "glad" tidings of their abode in jahanam, or is the lesson of the hadith given more as a reminder of the afterlife, hence, remembering where you will end up if you die as a disbeliever.